# Cannot login to Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Every time I try to log in to my Minecraft account, it asks me the security questions I have set for my account. However, it is not able to confirm my identity. Is there a specific reason for this and how would I fix this problem?

Comment: Are you trying to say you have to answer a security question every time you log in, even if it's on the same computer?

Answer (score 1):

This means that you have entered the answer incorrectly, this happened to me also, you can change the security question on your account.

It should give you the option after you have entered the answer incorrectly, and should say something like "why can't i access my account" or "reset my account details" or "Forgotten my password" I'm sorry i cant check this as it doesnt come up for me anymore.

If you click that button it will take you to a page that will ask for your email, enter it and a link will be sent to you requesting you change your question and answer.

Make sure it is something you will remember and just to let you know from what i can tell it is case sensitive.

Hope this helps